# python - YouTube API search().list_next() not working well

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-data-api

I'm using this code. But I get 50 results only. It does not show the next 50 results. I mean, it does not get the `nextPageToken`. Am I doing something wrong? Or search().list_next() doesn't work?

```
def youtube_search(options):
  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)


  req = youtube.search().list(
    q=options.q,
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=50,
    channelId="my_channel_id",      
    order="date",
    type="video"
  )

  while req:
   res = req.execute()
   for item in res["items"]:    
    if item["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":

      video_id=item["id"]["videoId"]
      video_title=item["snippet"]["title"]
      video_date=item["snippet"]["publishedAt"]   

      print("%s # %s # %s" % (video_id, video_title, video_date))


   req = youtube.search().list_next(req, res)
```

I'm seaching in my channel using **channelId**, I know I have more than 50 results.

The **maxResults**, is the results per page. (value by default is 50)

**q=options.q** is the query, a word to base the search results ('dog' for example)

Comment: What's `options.q`?

Comment: Could `maxResults=50` have something to do with it?

Comment: It is the query... a word.. the results are based in this word

Comment: maxResults=50 is the results per page... i want to see the next page